# Multilinear map with algebra

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I write this question "Introduction to Noncommutative Algebra" written by Bresar."6.1 Free Algebra p.139" 
I didn't show  that how f is multilinear.
Every F-algebra A,the map $(x_{1},...,x_{n})\longrightarrow f(x_{1},...,x_{n}),x_{i} \in A$,is multilinear.(F:filed,$1\in A$
 I don't know this subject well.I know definition of multilinear polynomial,but what is multilinear map ?

Comment: You haven't specified what $f$ is.

Comment: This doesn't mean anything. *What* is the question ? What is $f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bilinear map is one that is linear in two inputs.  In other words, 
\begin{align*}
f(ax_1+bx_2,cx_3+dx_4)&=f(ax_1,cx_3+dx_4)+f(bx_2,cx_3+dx_4)\\
&=f(ax_1,cx_3)+f(ax_1,dx_4)+f(bx_2,cx_3)+f(bx_2,dx_4)\\
&=ac\cdot f(x_1,x_3)+ad\cdot f(x_1,x_4)+bc\cdot f(x_2,x_3)+bd\cdot f(x_2,x_4)
\end{align*}

A multilinear map is one that is linear in all of its inputs (extend the properties above to arbitrary inputs).  Multilinear maps are generalizations of linear maps.

Comment: I write this question "Introduction to Noncommutative Algebra" written by Bresar."6.1 Free Algebra p.139"